# How to redirect users to login page in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to redirect users to the odoo log-in pages when they click a button in my form view for re-authentication.
I wanted to go through the actions URL route but that will make me hardcode the URL of the site where odoo is hosted of which I am trying to avoid, here is the function from where I want to redirect the users to the login page when the function is called.

```py
def authorize_execute_payments(self):
     {
            "type": "ir.actions.act_url",
            "url": "https://odoo.com",
            "target": "self",
        }
```

But I am not sure this is the right way, I will appreciate any help possible.

Answer (score 0):

While [the URL Action documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/actions.html#url-actions-ir-actions-act-url) only shows the use of a full URL, a URL Action can also use a relative URL. Examples of this can be seen in the Odoo core code [here (in Python)](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_demo.py#L12-L16) and [here (in XML)](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/views/base_menus.xml#L48-L52).

In your case, you may be able to just provide `"url": "/web/login",` to send the user to the login page directly.

*Make sure you are also returning the URL Action dictionary so that Odoo can know to use it.*

```py
def authorize_execute_payments(self):
    return {
        "type": "ir.actions.act_url",
        "url": "/web/login",
        "target": "self",
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an html link-button in an inherited template corresponding to the webpage you want ? :

```
<template id="myCuston-the-template" id='the-source-module.the-template'>
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('theodoodivclass')]" position="inside">
     
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/web/login?redirect=/thepag-url-to-be-redirected-after-login-suceeed">
    
    </xpath>
</template>
```